# How do I create an xPath statement from a NodeInfo?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, saxon

I'm using the S9API with Saxon 9.7 HE, and I have a NodeInfo object.  I need to create an xPath statement that uniquely corresponds to this NodeInfo.  It's easy enough to get the prefix, the node name, and the parent:

```
String prefix = node.getPrefix();
String localPart = node.getLocalPart();
NodeInfo parent = node.getParent();
```

So I can walk up the tree, building the xPath as I go.  But what I can't find is any way to get the positional predicate info.  IOW, it's not sufficient to create:

```
/persons/person/child
```

because it might match multiple child elements.  I need to create:

```
/persons/person[2]/child[1]
```

which will match only one child element.  Any ideas on how to get the positional predicate info?  Or maybe there's a better way to do this altogether?

BTW, for those who use the generic DOM and not the S9API, here's an easy solution to this problem:  http://practicalxml.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/practicalxml/DomUtil.html#getAbsolutePath(org.w3c.dom.Element)

---

**Edit**:  @Michael Kay's answer works. To add some meat to it:

```
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile("./path()");
List matches = (List) xPathExpression.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODESET);
String pathToNode = matches.get(0).toString();
// If you want to remove the expanded QName syntax:
pathToNode = pathToNode.replaceAll("Q\\{.*?\\}", "");
```

This must be done using the same xPath object that was previously used to acquire the NodeInfo object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath 3.0 you can use fn:path().

Earlier Saxon releases offer saxon:path().

The challenge here is handling namespaces. fn:path() returns a path that's not sensitive to namespace-prefix bindings by using the new expanded-QName syntax

```
/Q{}persons/Q{}person[2]/Q{}child[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative approach.  I never considered using xPath to solve the problem.  Question: Is it possible to return xPath that is *not* in the expanded-QName syntax?

Comment: No if you want something different you have to code it yourself. But it's easy enough to get the position: `let $n := . return 1 + count(preceding-sibling::*[node-name(.) = node-name($n)])`

Comment: Simpler answer:  Use the power of Java:  `pathToNode = pathToNode.replaceAll("Q\\{.*?\\}", "");`.

Comment: Or indeed the power of XPath: `replace(path($node), 'Q\{.*?\}', '')`